# audio player just in a home page

Tags: audio, wordpress

I'm triyng to use your audio player just in the home page of this site:
http://www.piscinafrancavilla.com/wordpress/
the home page is with super size... I need to put the audio with autoplay... I know that i should edit the header.php and put the condition

```
<?php if(is_home()) {?>
```

for use your plugin what is the rest of the script?
Do you think that is the right way???
Please help me
Best regards
Eric

Answer (score 0):

Use embed tag on your homepage as

```
<object width="199" height="59">
 <param name="src"
 value="song.mp3">
 <param name="autoplay" value="true">
 <param name="controller" value="true">
 <param name="bgcolor" value="#333333">
 <embed TYPE="application/x-mlayer2"
 src="song.mp3" autostart="true"
 loop="false" width="199" height="59" controller="true"
 bgcolor="#333333"></embed>
 </object>
```

Just change the src values (there are two) to the absolute URL of the music file you are wanting to insert.

Comment: Great Luigi, works good, little slow in downloading, but I think depend of the song size, for the rest I put condition in the header, just for the home page and works!!! Thank you very much!!! ;)

Comment: again... and if i would like to put more that one song??? How should be the embed tag???Thx

Comment: Are you talking about like a playlist?

Comment: In general accept this question and open another one i'll give you a answer. Ciao